# Is there a way to opt-out the download bar on the bottom of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I just think it's annoying, that every time when I download something in Chrome I need to manually click the bottom download bar to make it away. Is there a way to disable the download bar showing on the bottom ?

Or make it auto disappear after the initial download.

Or to open as another new tab directly without having it showing on the bottom of the download, which limit the viewable screen size.

Answer (score 8):

As of now there's [no way to disable/auto-hide it](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3275255c71e8ac9f&hl=en), though people [have been asking for it](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3275255c71e8ac9f&hl=en#all). Make yourself heard!

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple workaround: Opening the Downloads window and then closing it will remove the downloads bar.

On a Mac: Command-Shift-J, then Command-W